# Dynamically injecting a value into a Javadoc comment

Tags: java, javadoc

Currently, it is not possible to use the `@value` tag to dynamically inject a value into a Javadoc comment; `@value` tags can only refer to static fields.

This is problematic in my case because I have many subclasses that contain many overriden methods with slightly different Javadoc comments between them. Each time the documentation changes, I have to update the corresponding method in each subclass. With over 20 subclasses, this is becoming quite burdensome.

**Is there some way to dynamically inject a value into a Javadoc comment?**, i.e. define some sort of Javadoc template? I am open to any sort of solution, whether it be implementing some sort of custom tag or using a maven plugin.

**How my code currently looks:**

```java
abstract class A {

  int method1();

}

public class B extends A{
  /**
   * Returns the id of the corresponding B object.
   */
  int method1() {
    return super.method1();
  }
}

public class C extends A{
  /**
   * Returns the id of the corresponding C object.
   */
  int method1() {
    return super.method1();
  }
}
```

**How I would like it to look (or something following this general idea):**

```java
abstract class A {
  /**
   * Returns the id of the corresponding {@value getEntityName()}
   */
  int method1();

  abstract String getEntityName();
}

public class B extends A {
  String getEntityName() { return "B object"; }
}

public class C extends A {
  String getEntityName() { return "C object"; }
}
```

Comment: Can you just write "Returns the id of the object." here. Why would anyone need to override method and just invoke super.method() in its body?